# How can I write a select statement for mysql where I only do not want the second letter in the string?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to write a `select` statement for `mysql` where I want to exclude all strings that contain an `'a'` as the second letter. Here is my select statement so far. It works for the most part, but some still slip through for reason I do not understand.

```
Select title, replacement_cost, rating from film where title not like "-a%" and replacement_cost = 19.99
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the underscore as wildcard for a single character:

```
Select title, replacement_cost, rating 
from film 
where title not like "_a%" 
and replacement_cost = 19.99
```

[SQL Wildcards](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

or with [`SUBSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

```
Select title, replacement_cost, rating 
from film 
where SUBSTR(title, 2, 1) <> 'a'
and replacement_cost = 19.99
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, and I did not know about the SUBSTR command before now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
Select title, replacement_cost, rating from film where substr(title,2,1)!='a' and replacement_cost = 19.99
```